# Two WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do something like this query:

```
UPDATE `race_records` SET vehicle = SELECT name FROM vehicles WHERE model_id = 567 WHERE playerid = 3
```

But obviously it's incorrect and won't work.

I want to insert a string from `vehicles` into a row in `race_records` where playerid = 3.

Answer (score 2):

Use `AND` ?

```
UPDATE `race_records` 
SET vehicle = (SELECT name FROM vehicles
               WHERE model_id = 567 AND playerid = 3)
```

Or you want one `WHERE` in the inner query, and one `WHERE` on the outer , in this case:

```
UPDATE `race_records` 
SET vehicle = (SELECT name FROM vehicles
               WHERE model_id = 567)
WHERE playerid = 3
```